# How to delete a playing .wav file?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to build a audiobook using this code but after making the audio file 'my.wav' I want to delete it everytime after listening the audio automatically but it is returning error: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'my.wav'`.

My code:

```
from pygame import mixer
import os
import pyttsx3


engine=pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate',165)
engine.save_to_file('my name is unkown','my.wav')
engine.runAndWait()

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('my.wav')
mixer.music.play()

os.remove('my.wav')
```

Comment: why is `tkinter` tagged?

Comment: Haven't done a lot of research, but the problem is that windows does not allow you to delete a file that is open in another program. You have your mp3 file open and playing (`mixer.music.load()`, `mixer.music.play()`), so I guess you just need to quit the mixer. You can do this with `mixer.music.quit()`. NOTE: there probably is a solution that doesn't quit the mixer, although I don't know if it yields any advantage

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing this line of code before trying to delete the file.

```
mixer.music.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mixer.music.get_busy()` to check whether the music is still playing, if not, then use `mixer.music.unload()` to release the file before deleting it:

```py
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('my.wav')
mixer.music.play()

# wait until the playing is completed
while mixer.music.get_busy(): pass
# unload the loaded music file
mixer.music.unload()

os.remove('my.wav')
```